# Does ruby support an enumerable map_cons method or its equivalent?

Tags: arrays, ruby, cons

Ruby has a handy function for enumerables called [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).  Which "Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive  elements."  This is really nice.  Except that this is definitely an `each` method, which returns nil upon completion and not an array of the values you've looped over like `map` would.

However, if I have a situation where I need to iterate over an enumerable type, take an element and its cons, then perform some operation on them and return them back into an array what can I do?  Normally, I'd use map for this sort of behavior.  But `map_cons` doesn't exist.

An example:

Given a list of integers, I need to see which ones of those integers repeat and return a list of just those integers

```
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2] ## I need some function that will get me [1, 2]
```

I can say:

```
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2].each_cons(2) {|e| e[0] if e[0] == e[1]}
```

But, since it `each`s over the array, it will complete successfully and return `nil` at the end.  I need it to behave like `map` and not like `each`.

Is this behavior something that ruby supports? Am I coming at it from the wrong direction entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation of each_cons ends with this innocent phrase: "If no block is given, returns an enumerator." Most methods of Enumerable do this. What can you do with an Enumerator? [Nothing truly impressive](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) . But Enumerators include Enumerable, which does provide a large amount of powerful methods, `map` being one of them. So, as Stefan Pochmann does:

```
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2].each_cons(2).map { |e| e[0] if e[0] == e[1] }
```

`each_cons`is called without a block, so it returns an Enumerator. `map`is simply one of its methods.

Comment: Since we're dealing with pairs, consider using `map { |a, b| a if a == b }`.

Comment: Perhaps not truly impressive, but enumerators without blocks can still be handy. For example,  `enum = [:even, :odd].cycle #=> #<Enumerator: [:even, :odd]:cycle>; enum.next; #=> :even; enum.next #=> :odd; enum.next #=> :even`...

Answer (score 5):

Just add `map`?

```
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2].each_cons(2).map { |e| e[0] if e[0] == e[1] }
=> [1, nil, nil, nil, nil, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.7 added the method [filter_map](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) which makes this even easier:

```
p [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2].each_cons(2).filter_map{|a,b| a if a == b} # => [1, 2]
```